# Selectively omit frame pointer in MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

In GCC i can selectively set optimization flags for specific function, so this:

```
void func() {}
```

generates:

```
func():
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

And this:

```
__attribute__((optimize("-fomit-frame-pointer")))
void func() {}
```

generates:

```
func():
        nop
        ret
```

How can i do the same in visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a command line parameter to the compiler, `/Oy`, this makes the compiler to omit frame pointers. You can achieve the same with `#pragma`:

```
#pragma optimize("y", on)

int foo(int a) { // foo will be compiled with omitted frame pointers
    return a;
}

#pragma optimize("y", off)
```

Here, `foo()` will be compiled with omitted frame pointers.

Note: As I see, you have to build an optimized build to make this option have an effect. So, either supply some optimization flag to the compiler (like "/Og"), or include "g" into the pragma: `#pragma optimize("gy", ...)`

(I've checked this with Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: FYI, VS2022 gives `'y': invalid character in pragma optimization list` warning

Comment: Seem like an issue with the compiler, [msdn lists it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170) as a supported option